# insert with unnest function - skips a number in serial column

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql, auto-increment

I am trying to use the `unnest` function in `insert`. While doing so, the serial skips a number for each insert.

```
mydb=# \d tab1  
                         Table "public.tab1"  
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers                         
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------  
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('tab1_id_seq'::regclass)  
 col1   | integer |   
 col2   | integer |   
Indexes:  
    "tab1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)  
  
mydb=# insert into tab1(id,col1,col2) values (nextval('tab1_id_seq'),1,unnest(array[4,5]));  
INSERT 0 2  
mydb=# select * from tab1;  
 id | col1 | col2   
----+------+------  
  1 |    1 |    4  
  2 |    1 |    5  
(2 rows)  
  
mydb=# insert into tab1(id,col1,col2) values (nextval('tab1_id_seq'),2,unnest(array[4,5]));  
INSERT 0 2  
mydb=# select * from tab1;  
 id | col1 | col2   
----+------+------  
  1 |    1 |    4  
  2 |    1 |    5  
  4 |    2 |    4  
  5 |    2 |    5  
(4 rows)  
  
mydb=# insert into tab1(col1,col2) values(2,unnest(array[4,5]));  
INSERT 0 2  
mydb=# select * from tab1;  
 id | col1 | col2   
----+------+------  
  1 |    1 |    4  
  2 |    1 |    5  
  4 |    2 |    4  
  5 |    2 |    5  
  7 |    2 |    4  
  8 |    2 |    5  
(6 rows)  
  
mydb=# insert into tab1(col2) values(unnest(array[4,5]));  
INSERT 0 2  
mydb=# select * from tab1;  
 id | col1 | col2   
----+------+------  
  1 |    1 |    4  
  2 |    1 |    5  
  4 |    2 |    4  
  5 |    2 |    5  
  7 |    2 |    4  
  8 |    2 |    5  
 10 |      |    4  
 11 |      |    5  
(8 rows)  

mydb=# select nextval('tab1_id_seq');  
 nextval   
---------  
      13  
(1 row)
```

For every `insert` it skips a number in the `id` column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unnest` returns multiple rows, so using it inside a single row of `VALUES` is a bit of a hack. Although it does work, it appears that the `nextval` call is somehow evaluated twice.

You can write an insert as `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` rather than `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`: in PostgreSQL, `VALUES` is just a row constructor. So consider writing something like this:

```
insert into tab1(col1, col2) select 1, unnest(array[4,5])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the unnest function in the from clause of an `insert ... select` it doesn't skip the extra IDs.

As:

```
insert into tab1(col1,col2)
select
   1, u.val
from
   unnest(array[4,5]) as u(val);
```

I think by putting it in a values clause you're running foul of a deprecated postgresql specific extension.  The [Postgresql Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html) says about this:

> Currently, functions returning sets can also be called in the select
>   list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the
>   function returning set is invoked, and an output row is generated for
>   each element of the function's result set. Note, however, that this
>   capability is deprecated and might be removed in future releases.

Comment: What does the `as u(val)` bit do here?

Comment: @sleighty the u(val) bit gives names to the result of the unnest function.  The "u" is the table name, and the "val" is the name for the column within it.