# How do I insert multiple records into my postgres database using Slonik?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, slonik

I am a front end developer and this is my first time using [Slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik/) with postgresql.

I want to know how I can make this query dynamic by inserting the data (which is hardcoded) using function parameters:

```js
const addMany = async (connection = slonik) => {
  const useResult = await connection.query(sql`
    INSERT into 
      users (username, email) 
    VALUES 
      ('amite', 'amite@gmail.com'),
      ('nilesh', 'nil@gmail.com'),
      ('nikhil', 'nik@gmail.com')
      RETURNING *;
  `);

  return useResult;
};
```

Do I need to create tuples using string concatenation? I am confused

```js
      ('amite', 'amite@gmail.com'),
      ('nilesh', 'nil@gmail.com'),
      ('nikhil', 'nik@gmail.com')
```

What I have tried so far is:

```js
const addManyUsers = async(connection = slonik) => {
  const keys = [
    'username', 'email'
  ];
  
  const values = [
    ['nilesh', 'bailey'],
    ['nilesh@gmail.com', 'bailey@gmail.com']
  ]
  
  const identifiers = keys.map((key) => {
    return sql.identifier([key]);
  });
  
  const query = sql`
    INSERT INTO users
      (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
    VALUES
      (${sql.unnest(values, sql`, `)})
    RETURNING *
  `
  const records = await connection.query(query)
  return records
}
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
(node:5975) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: **Column types length must match tuple member length.**
    at Object.createUnnestSqlFragment (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/slonik/dist/sqlFragmentFactories/createUnnestSqlFragment.js:29:19)
    at Object.createSqlTokenSqlFragment (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/slonik/dist/factories/createSqlTokenSqlFragment.js:27:39)
    at sql (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/slonik/dist/factories/createSqlTag.js:39:65)
    at addManyUsers (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/app/models/db.js:58:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/app/models/db.js:72:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5975) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5975) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is what my table structure looks like. I am using `varchar(50)
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

@RaghavGarg. here is the updated code as per your suggestion:

```js
const keys = [
  'username',
  'email',
];

const identifiers = keys.map((key) => {
  return sql.identifier([key]);
});

const values = [
  ['nilesh', 'nilesh@gmail.com'], // single full record
  ['bailey', 'bailey@gmail.com'], // single full record
]

const values_types = ['varchar', 'varchar'];

const main = async(connection = slonik) => {
  let query = sql`
    INSERT INTO users
      (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
    VALUES
      (${sql.unnest(values, values_types)})
    RETURNING *
  `
  try {
    const results = await connection.query(query)
    console.log(results);
    return results
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

main()
```

The query above expands out to:

```js
{
  sql: '\n' +
    'INSERT INTO users\n' +
    '  ("username", "email")\n' +
    'VALUES\n' +
    '  (unnest($1::"varchar(50)"[], $2::"varchar(50)"[]))\n' +
    'RETURNING *\n',
  type: 'SLONIK_TOKEN_SQL',
  values: [
    [ 'nilesh', 'bailey' ],
    [ 'nilesh@gmail.com', 'bailey@gmail.com' ]
  ]
}
```

The error I get from this now is:

```
error: type "varchar(50)[]" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/shreekant/Documents/code/node/postgres-starter/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  length: 100,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42704',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '81',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_type.c',
  line: '274',
  routine: 'typenameType',
  notices: []
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the final value of the variable `query` before executing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what finally worked. I needed to use a `SELECT * FROM` instead of `VALUES`

```sql
let query = sql`
    INSERT INTO users
      (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
    SELECT * FROM
      ${sql.unnest(values, values_types)}
    RETURNING *
  `
```

Here is the whole function:

```js
const keys = [
  'username',
  'email',
];

const identifiers = keys.map((key) => {
  return sql.identifier([key]);
});

const values = [
  ['nilesh', 'nilesh@gmail.com'], // single full record
  ['bailey', 'bailey@gmail.com'], // single full record
]

const values_types = [`varchar`,`varchar`];

const main = async(connection = slonik) => {
  let query = sql`
    INSERT INTO users
      (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
    SELECT * FROM
      ${sql.unnest(values, values_types)}
    RETURNING *
  `
  try {
    const results = await connection.query(query)
    console.log(results);
    return results
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

main()
```

This is what the query now expands to:

```sql
{
  sql: '\n' +
    'INSERT INTO users\n' +
    '  ("username", "email")\n' +
    'SELECT * FROM\n' +
    '  unnest($1::"varchar"[], $2::"varchar"[])\n' +
    'RETURNING *\n',
  type: 'SLONIK_TOKEN_SQL',
  values: [
    [ 'nilesh', 'bailey' ],
    [ 'nilesh@gmail.com', 'bailey@gmail.com' ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ohh, nice find. I missed, `SELECT * FROM ` incase of `unnest`. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with the arguments passed to method `sql.unnest`. It takes the **data array** as the first argument and **type array** as the second argument.

That's what the error also says

> Column types length must match tuple member length

So your code should change to something like

```js
const values_types = ['text', 'text'];

const query = sql`
  INSERT INTO users
    (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
  VALUES
    (${sql.unnest(values, values_types)})
  RETURNING *
`
```

Docs for [`sql.unnest`](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#sqlunnest)

> (
> tuples: $ReadOnlyArray<$ReadOnlyArray>,
> columnTypes: $ReadOnlyArray
> ): UnnestSqlTokenType;

---

Also, you should consider wrapping your code in `try/catch` block and handle the errors properly.

> (node:5975) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

---

#### Update 1

The variable `value_types` is an array containing the type for each column that your inserting using the query.

So `value_types` should always have an equal number of elements as of any member of `values`

```js
values[i].length === values_types.length
```

and every index in types array should correspond to the correct value of a member. So

```js
// for
values_types = ["text", "text", "int4"]

// any values[i] should be
values[i] = ["nilesh", "nilesh@gmail.com", 123]
```

---

I missed one thing, the `values` is also wrong, every member should be a single valid record i.e. all the column values for a single record.

The variable should look something like this

```js
const values = [
  ['nilesh', 'nilesh@gmail.com'], // single full record
  ['bailey', 'bailey@gmail.com'], // single full record
]
```

So your final code look something like this

```js
const values = [
  ['nilesh', 'nilesh@gmail.com'], // single full record
  ['bailey', 'bailey@gmail.com'], // single full record
]

const values_types = ['text', 'text'];

const query = sql`
  INSERT INTO users
    (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
  VALUES
    (${sql.unnest(values, values_types)})
  RETURNING *
`
```

Comment: my data looks like this:

```
const values = [
    ['nilesh', 'bailey'],
    ['nilesh@gmail.com', 'bailey@gmail.com']
  ]
```

This is a nested array and does not match the `value_types` you have mentioned. How do Insert nested arrays?

Comment: I tried changing `value types` to `[['text'], ['text']];` but that doesn't work either :(

Comment: @AmitErandole I have updated the code with more explanation, please check it out and share if it is still not working. Also, let me know if there is still any doubt.

Comment: I tried this already. The error I get from the above code is:

` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: function unnest(text[], text[]) does not exist`

Actually those columns are `varchar ` (see update in screenshot above)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, your code seems right to me, can you try to run the raw query inside of DB?? `INSERT INTO users ("username", "email") VALUES (unnest(ARRAY[ 'nilesh', 'bailey' ]::varchar(50)[], ARRAY[ 'nilesh@gmail.com', 'bailey@gmail.com' ]::varchar(50)[])) RETURNING *` I have removed the double quotes from around the varchar(50).

Comment: Ok just tried that. Now I get `Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 10:  (unnest([ 'nilesh', 'bailey' ]::varchar(50)[], [ 'nilesh@gm...`

Comment: Could I be doing unnest all wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295572/how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-values-from-two-arrays-in-postgres

I am totally new to this so I can't interpret this properly

Comment: I got it working @Raghav. I need to learn most about postgres to figure this out honestly

Answer (score 0):

If the server does not support `unnest`:

```
  const values = [
    { username: 'nilesh', email: 'nilesh@gmail.com' },
    { username: 'bailey', email: 'bailey@gmail.com' },
  ];

  const addMany = async connection => {
    const useResult = await connection.query(sql`
      INSERT INTO users (username, email)
      VALUES
        ${sql.join(
          values.map(({ username, email }) => sql`(${username}, ${email})`),
          sql`,`,
        )}
      RETURNING *;
    `);

    return useResult;
  };
```